# Is it possible to train a QNN in parallel so that all qubits in the quantum computer can be utlised?

Tags: qiskit

I wish to use quantum machine learning to help forecast temperature by using a dataset with 5 different features. I had currently achieved this using Qiskit with 5 qubits, with ZZfeaturemap and RealAmplitude. However, the training takes a super long time on my local PC simulator, so before I try it on the actual quantum computer, I was wondering if there is a way to train the model in parallel, that is, train with multiple data at once and then merge the result together so I can take advantage of all the qubits that a quantum computer offers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're training with a gradient-based optimizer, one way to parallelize is through minibatch gradient descent. Say $\ell(\theta, x)$ is the loss for your model's output given a training point $x$ when the gate parameters are $\theta$. With ordinary gradient descent, your goal is to estimate the gradient of your loss using the $N$ training data you are provided, e.g.$^1$
$$
\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta} \approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\ell(\theta +\Delta \theta, x_i) - \ell(\theta, x_i)}{\Delta \theta}. \tag{1}
$$
Then after computing this quantity, you update your gate parameters, e.g. $\theta \leftarrow \theta - \eta \frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta}$. Every element in the sum in (1) may be evaluated independently and so it is highly parallelizable. However, usually using the entire training data of $N$ points is overkill and so you can estimate the quantity in (1) using some number $N_{batch}$ of data much smaller than $N$. As $N_{batch}$ gets smaller the training is less parallelizable in this way, but can often converge using fewer total resources. The case where $N_{batch}=1$ is called stochastic gradient descent and is very common to use (but not at all parallelizable in this manner).

If you plan on evaluating many circuits in parallel on a chip, you should be aware that each set of qubits might yield very different estimates for $\ell(\theta, x)$ due to the variation in noise and qubit imperfections across a device, as well as nonlocal effects like crosstalk (assuming you are not using a fault tolerant quantum computer of course). This might make it hard for your model parameters to converge.

---

$^1$This is an example of approximating a gradient numerically. One can compute gradients of quantum circuit outputs exactly using techniques like the "parameter shift rule".

Comment: I see, so essentially I can use multiple circuits in parallel to make a prediction at the same time, I then calculate the loss value for them together which will be passed to the optimizer to improve the model. Thank you so much.